# Using /tags/tag-name/media/recent catch non-recent media

Tags: instagram

I have this Real-time subscription to the tag #montreal. When I get 10 hits on that, I start querying this endpoint:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/montreal/media/recent?client_id=[MyClientId]&min_tag_id=[LastMinTagId]

I get my last min tag id value from my DB, the last time I ran this query I saved it there.

Next, parsing these media, I look for 4 specific tags (#summer, #toronto, #love and #people) in the media's caption text. Basically I want only the "new images" that are submitted with #montreal and at least one of the 4 specific ones. When I find one of those images, I save some reference into my DB.

My problem is that I see images that are weeks old in the list I'm collecting (and saving to DB) and I don't know why. Here is the c# snippet I use to parse the media and make sure they are valid to me.

```
// Caption text must contain main tag and at least 1 weekly tag for image to be valid
if (instagramMedia.Caption == null || !instagramMedia.Caption.Text.Contains("#" + mainTag.Name) || !weeklyTags.Any(wt => instagramMedia.Caption.Text.Contains("#" + wt.Name)))
{
    continue;
}
```

My worry, is that this code runs correctly (because for most images it's ok), but from time to time, I see an image coming into my like that already has 100+ likes. I look at it's date created, and it's 2 weeks old.

My understanding of instagram media is that once caption text is set, it cannot be modified. Is that right?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instagram caption can be modified later if no one has commented on it yet, you can delete an existing caption and add another.

You can use `capiton.created_time` in your check to avoid older media